# What is the difference of Chameleon 100% between Morrowind and Oblivion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

In *The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion*, once you enchant some items with Chameleon effect and you get 100% or more of the effect, the game becomes too easy, almost feels like cheating. No one can see you, you can go everywhere you want, kill whoever you want, steal whatever you want.

I've never been able to get Chameleon 100% in *The Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind*, but I'd like to know if it works the same way as in Oblivion.

Comment: Wasn't there something weird about 100% in Oblivion that still allowed you to be spotted?  I remember I had to go past 100% for one reason or another.

Comment: My roommate recently started a throw-away character for Oblivion and has been running around with 100% chameleon. I never knew it had those effects at 100% until I saw him do it!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It appears to work similarly, though at a lower percentage.

[Oblivion's Chameleon at 100%](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Chameleon) (emphasis mine):

> It is possible to combine multiple Chameleon enchantments to reach 100% Chameleon, **causing your character to be visually non-existent and nearly completely undetectable while performing any actions. NPCs will only interact with you if they are scripted to by a current quest or if a guard is attempting to arrest you.** Values higher than 100% are possible, but do not provide any additional benefit. **With 100% Chameleon, you are able to move freely throughout the game, killing, stealing, sneaking, and doing almost whatever you want without ever being seen or confronted. You are basically invisible to all living creatures or people within the game.** However, you can still be damaged by items or traps.

So essentially in Oblivion, 100% Chameleon, as you stated in the question, makes you basically invisible, allowing you to get away with whatever you want.

A similar effect appears in [Morrowind](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Chameleon) (emphasis mine):

> If the Magnitude of the Chameleon effect is high enough, **no object will be able to spot you under various conditions, seemingly based on Fight rating. 75% Chameleon seems to be sufficient to walk right past hostile NPCs without issue.**

So it seems that the same ability to move around undetected exists in Morrowind, though unlike in Oblivion, it occurs at 75% Chameleon (as opposed to 100%).

Comment: Interesting, but has anyone played Morrowind with Chameleon 75 or 100% in order to confirm this answer?

Comment: "I noticed that wearing the ring of surroundings (30% chameleon) is enough for my character to constantly backstab opponents (with sneak/agility/luck maxed out), if I crouch during combat just in front of enemies they stop fighting immediately and worse they flee when I approach them [...] Chameleon effect is clearly responsible of this, without this effect activated my character can be spotted. I can imagine being totally undetectable with a 100% chameleon but 30% seems a little bit low for the same result." — [Unsigned comment by Plectrius](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind_talk:Chameleon)

Comment: @Ethan - Conformation is probably a long time coming if you can get away with 30%. "Unfortunately, Chameleon checks aren't logged unless you are also Sneaking, making it difficult (if not impossible) to obtain hard data on how Chameleon effects work unless you are also Sneaking."

Comment: @Ethan, [OpenMW's reverse-engineering](https://wiki.openmw.org/index.php?title=Research:NPC_AI_Behaviour) says it's 75%.

Comment: Incidentally, 100% Chameleon in Morrowind is not enough to guarantee some rolls, e.g. if you have 100 Sneak and 100% Chameleon and attempt to pickpocket someone in front of them, your roll can still fail and be detected.

Answer (score 2):

Chameleon plays a number of different roles in Morrowind gameplay:

1. If your Chameleon rating is 75 or greater, NPCs will mostly not engage in "casual interactions" with you: they won't turn to face you as you walk by, they won't initiate dialog, they won't attack you even if their aggression level is high.
2. It factors into your ability to sneak, but there's no hard threshold above which Chameleon makes it impossible to fail.  Rather, you gain sneak bonuses from your luck, agility, sneak skill, Chameleon level, and distance from an observer.  These are countered by the observer's luck, agility, sneak skill, blindness level, and the weight of your boots.
3. It factors into your ability to dodge hits in combat.  Mods can change the strength of the effect, but by default, you need 500% Chameleon to get the maximum effect.  Even with the maximum Chameleon bonus, it's possible for an attacker to accumulate enough attack bonuses to completely negate it.

Chameleon in Morrowind is a powerful effect, but unlike in Oblivion, there is no threshold above which it acts as an "I win" button.